# Ubuntu thinks multiple people are logged in

Tags: users

On my Ubuntu 21.04, when I go to restart or shut down through the system menu (top right > `Power Off / Log Off` > `Restart...` / `Power Off...`), it always says that other users are logged in and prompts me for a password even though I am the user that is still logged in. This is a fresh install of Ubuntu. Also, I only have one video card.

Here is my output of `w`:

```
$ w
 15:14:38 up 3 min,  1 user,  load average: 1.35, 0.52, 0.19
USER     TTY      FROM             LOGIN@   IDLE   JCPU   PCPU WHAT
newo     :1       :1               15:12   ?xdm?   4:55   0.00s /usr/libexec/gd
```

It seems like my computer is also getting stuck in the `Activities` menu if I do a certain thing.

Any ideas on how to solve this?

Thanks!

Comment: Have you got `MultiseatX` enabled ?

Comment: @user535733, yes. It only has me listed.

Comment: @AnoopD, how would I check?

Comment: Should I try a reinstall?

Comment: @Newo Do you have multiple video cards installed  ?

Comment: Can you share with us the output of the 'who' command on your machine?

Comment: @user535733, ah, OK.

Comment: I think I'll try reinstalling and seeing if this problem still occurs.

Comment: How do you restart/shutdown?  From the menu or within a terminal with `sudo restart`, for example?

Answer (score 0):

Downloading a new ISO and reinstalled fixed this issue. There was most likely some corruption (or something else) that caused this.